# Mongo Repository find by condition is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoRepository query method which needs to fetch data based on conditions.

I have the following record in database.

```
{
'name' : 'test',
'show' : false,
'free' : true
}
```

And the following query, But the query doesn't return this record.

```
repositiry.findByNameNotNullAndShowIsTrueOrFreeIsTrue()
```

as per the condition, `Name` is `not null` and `Free` is `True`. But Why am I not getting the record.

Comment: Maybe it will help you. Try in mongo console: `db.test.insert({a: "true"});db.test.find({});db.test.find({a: true});` In this case you will see that no records found. Because the code try to find `{a: true}` not `{a: "true"}`. Check real types of your properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario. It's working here. The query logged was correct.

```
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "name": {
                "$ne": null
            },
            "show": true
        },
        {
            "free": true
        }
    ]
}
```

To enable the mongodb query logs you must DEBUG MongoTemplate.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate = DEBUG
```

Entity

```
@Document
@Data
@Builder
class Entity {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean show;
    private boolean free;
}
```

Repository

```
interface EntityRepository extends MongoRepository<Entity,String> {

    List<Entity> findByNameIsNotNullAndShowIsTrueOrFreeIsTrue();
}
```

Test

```
@Test
    public void testQuery() {
        repository.deleteAll();

        Entity entity = Entity.builder()
                .free(true)
                .show(false)
                .name("test")
                .build();
        repository.save(entity);

        List<Entity> entities = repository.findByNameIsNotNullAndShowIsTrueOrFreeIsTrue();

        Assert.assertEquals(1, entities.size());
    }
```